# Making a new environment with \NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: environments

I am making a new environment that takes two arguments.  The text within the environment is then written down.

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[2]
  { \noindent Declaration \ #1 \ (#2) }
  {}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Ramanujan}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter {This is an introduction
  to some topic}

\section{Test}

Some Text Here


\begin{myenv}{ID}{TITLE}
  Some Text
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I would like to do this with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.

Comment: Alan has answered the question, but you should probably define the inner code as a theorem or one item list environment, not \noindent this will take care of many details notably preventing page break just after or in the heading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of `\NewDocumentEnvironment`has the following format:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{name}{parameter specification}
    {beginning of environment}
    {end of environment}
```

The parameter specifications are much richer than the regular `\newenvironment`, but for translating a simple `\newenvironment` statement, the relevant parameter specification is `m`, (meaning "mandatory") one for each argument.  So your environment would be defined as follows:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{mm}
    {\noindent Declaration \ #1 \  (#2) }
    {}
```